# Find Duplicates in integer array and print them in actual order in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, duplicates, hashtable

I have problem finding the solution of my Question over the internet.

I have an integer array with both positive and negative numbers. like below

```
int arr[] = {56, 1, -1, 89, 89, 7 ,0, 5, 5, 56, 0,9 22, 33,67, 7, -1}
```

I need to find all the duplicates in the array.
The output need to be displayed (please note order is maintained) as below:

```
 56 -1 89 7 0 5
```

I know that duplicates can be found using hash in O(n) time. But I have facing problem in maintaining order.
Also I am not quite aware of C++ standard hash.

Can anyone suggest me, how to do it in C++. STL usage is allowed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I would downvote it but I've run out of votes:(

Comment: Apart from the objection by @πάνταῥεῖ, your question is also unclear. Several alternative solutions are possible but depend on additional constraints such as: Can the input array be modified? If not, how much additional space can we use? What are the time complexity requirements: is a trivial O(n^2) acceptable? Etc.

Comment: Initial array should not be modified. Output should be placed in another array. Time complexity less than O(n^2). 
Looking for some optimal solution with minimum space complexity.

Comment: @MartinJames: The OP changed the question to not just ask for code anymore.  Now it's just asking for an algorithm to generate a list of duplicates in order of first appearance, rather than order of detection as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Scan the input array for duplicates in reverse order, tracking the last occurrence of duplicates.  Then reverse that list, and you'll have a list of duplicates in order of first appearance in the input array.

e.g.

- loop from end to start of the input array
- add each value to an unordered set
- if the value was already present, it's a duplicate.  Add it to a list of duplicates
  (a map of `value->position`), replacing any previous value.

After scanning the input array completes, sort the duplicate list by position, and put those values into a list.

Using an unordered set and a separate duplicate-list with a position reduces storage overhead compared to every entry (even non-duplicates) having a position and a duplicate-count.  It also reduces the time taken if there are only a few duplicates.  (Since you don't have to walk through the whole set of all values finding only the ones with repeat-count > 1.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. That would help.